# How to update Xero invoice using xero-Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, xero-api

I have integrate xero with my app for my accounts and billing. Now I want to update an invoice which is already created in past on xero. Is there any solution for that?? Any suggestion will be highly appreciable.

Comment: Please provide your existing code and/or anything you have already tried. Try reading through the docs. Here is a related github issue: https://github.com/XeroAPI/xero-node/issues/219

Comment: Did you understand the question??? @Profit??

Answer (score 2):

I have the following code which works to append new item "new thing" to an invoice.

```
app.post('/invoicemodify', async (req, res) => {

let xero = new XeroClient(config);

let invoicemodify = await xero.invoices.update({
"InvoiceID": "*insert Invoice ID*",
"LineItems": [
{
  "Description": "Consulting services as agreed (20% off standard rate)",
  "Quantity": "10",
  "UnitAmount": "100.00",
  "AccountCode": "200",
  "DiscountRate": "20"
},
{
  "Description": "new thing",
  "Quantity": "1",
  "UnitAmount": "100.00",
  "AccountCode": "200",
  "DiscountRate": "50"
}
]
});

console.log("modify POST worked");




});
```